# parsing date error in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format.

```
[type] => mapper_parsing_exception
[reason] => failed to parse [prod_added_on]
[caused_by] => Array(
    [type] => illegal_argument_exception
    [reason] => Invalid format: "2010-12-27 07:15:06" /* is malformed at */ "10-12-27 07:15:06"
)
```

Following is my code to map date

```
'date' => [
     'type' => 'date',
     'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
],
```

Comment: The error is about the field `prod_added_on`. What's the mapping of that field?

Comment: I figured it out by re-indexing. Thank you for your reply